# what's wrong with my insert query (multi-part) exception

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to insert data from one table to another table (both are in different DB but in the same server).

here is the structure of the table

I have a table "synAtlasDB_tblVegetationType" have the following columns

1. VegTypeCode
2. VegetationClassID

I am trying to insert "VegetationClassID" to table "tblVegetationType" based on the condition that is VegTypeCode should be equal in both table

```
insert into dbo.tblVegetationType (VegetationClassID)
select VegetationClassID
from dbo.synAtlasDB_tblVegetationType where dbo.synAtlasDB_tblVegetationType.VegetationTypeCode = dbo.tblVegetationType.VegTypeCode
```

but this throws the exception:

> The multi-part identifier "dbo.tblVegetationType.VegTypeCode" could not be bound.

Comment: wrap values() around select statement

Comment: I think `insert into select` doesn't need `values()`; the problem is, he did not join those tables like `from dbo.synAtlasDB_tblVegetationType join dbo.tblVegetationType
on dbo.synAtlasDB_tblVegetationType.VegetationTypeCode=dbo.tblVegetationType.VegTypeCode`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is `UPDATE` not `INSERT`

```
UPDATE  veg
SET     veg.VegetationClassID = vegType.VegetationClassID
FROM    dbo.tblVegetationType veg
        INNER JOIN dbo.synAtlasDB_tblVegetationType vegType
            ON vegType.VegetationTypeCode = veg.VegTypeCode
```

Comment: Thank God, i just noticed i used Insert in the statement